# how to test schemaless insertion benchmark using taosdemo in TDengine database?

Tags: tdengine

I do the research on TDengine's official documentation, but the interface parameter setting only includes taosc, rest, and stmt. Does anyone know where can I find the right way or the right tool to the schemaless insertion benchmark?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `iface` option to `"sml"`
`line_protocol` option to the protocol you want to test, there are `"line", "telnet", "json"` three options.